# Is it good practice to define a function with different arguments list from reference in javascript?

Tags: javascript

For example, I working with a framework that would invoke a custom function like this:

```js
var ret = Module_Init(index, clk, obj);
```

The function `Module_Init` should be defined by user. And in my `Module_Init`, I only need the first parameter `index`. So I define it like this:

```js
function Module_Init(index)
{
    m_Index = index;
    // initialize code...
}
```

It work, but is it a good practice in Javascript?

Comment: It's not good practice to pass unused arguments, you could confuse other developers reading your code. This also leads to a messy codebase. Get rid of them if you don't need then.

Comment: IMO it doesn't really matter.  There aren't any downsides to doing that, and the code is simpler to follow if only slightly.  BTW you made a typo on `Index`

Comment: @DanStarns Since the *framework* is invoking it, I think it's fine. You don't worry about the parameters you often don't use when using `Array.prototype.forEach` either

Comment: @CertainPerformance my point is, you don't need to declare them in your code.

Comment: I can't really decide if this is one of those questions that should be closed, because the answer really comes down to opinion rather than a concrete indisputable fact.  Especially because I think the question about style is a valid and useful one.

Comment: Voted to close as this really is opinion based. Perhaps [*Currying*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113780/javascript-curry-what-are-the-practical-applications) is a better approach.

Comment: @user120242 Fixed typo. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use them, why put them in the function

Comment: The framework pass these parameters. User need to define the function accordingly. But user don't need use all these parameters passing by framework in my case. Thanks.